# Update statement - java with sqlite3

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I have weird problem with my UPDATE statement.

```
Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:project.db");
      c.setAutoCommit(false);

      stmt = c.createStatement();
      String idstring = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type stormtroopers's id:");
      int id = Integer.parseInt(idstring);
      String newrank = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type stormtrooper's new rank:");
      String sql = "UPDATE stormtrooper SET rank="+newrank+" WHERE id="+id+";";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      c.commit();
      stmt.close();
      c.close();

              jTextArea1.setText("Updated successfully");  
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
              jTextArea1.setText( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            }
```

When I try to type some rank, like "Private" I have an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: no such column: Private
```

But when I once mistakenly typed some number, like "1" - it updated rank successfully.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: post your table definition ( could be that youve defined rank as an integer ). ifso redefine as varchar and put single quotes around the newrank..

Comment: Rank is varchar and I got red underline when I try to put single quote aroud newrank like this -  String sql = "UPDATE stormtrooper SET rank="+'newrank'+" WHERE id="+id+";";

Comment: should be more like : "UPDATE stormtrooper SET rank='"+newrank+"' WHERE id="+id+";"; this will build the sql string correctly (assuming id part is ok )

Comment: Oh right, I totally forgot about this! Thanks, this case is solved.